# How to know status of time of daemon/service stopped on linux server?

Tags: linux, service

How to know time or date of daemon/service stopped on linux server?

Answer (score 1):

Check the service/daemons log files.

You may need to review its config file to find where they are located on Linux. Configuration files are typically found in /etc.

Logs are commonly found in /var/log on Linux.

Checking /var/log/messages is also a good place to look.